# Use SLComposeViewController to send message with Facebook messenger

Tags: ios, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to launch a Share extension of Facebook Messenger from my app so a user could easily send a message to one of his friend using the share extension. 
To my understanding it's done with SLComposeViewController where in the service name I give the facebook messenger service name. I tried to user as a service name : com.facebook.Messenger but it doesn't work. 
Anyone knows how this should be done?

However I can't